# C Macro to write a stack variable length struct?

Tags: c, list, variables, macros, declaration

I don't know if this is possible but I'd like to write a macro that
declare a variable length struct on the stack. I want to do something like this:

```
#define STATICLIST(max)       struct SStaticList { int iSize; id iObjects[max]; }
```

and the call it like this:

```
STATICLIST(32) Size32List
STATICLIST(64) Size64List
```

But I'm getting redeclaration of the type struct SStaticList errors

Comment: For what it's worth, C++ templates support this sort of thing reasonably well. :)

Comment: I know I know I've been a long time C++ programmer but I'm now developing for the iPhone and I don't like to mix C and C++.

Comment: Just as a side remark, I think the correct type for the `iSize` field would be `size_t`.

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like that, but you'll need something in order to avoid structs with the same conflicting name.

```
#define STATICLIST(max) struct { int iSize; id iObjects[max]; }
```

this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the token pasting operation ## to include the size in the structure name:

```
#define STATICLIST(max)       struct SStaticList##max { int iSize; int iObjects[max]; }
```

Comment: this would result in error when macro is used several times with same argument

Comment: That's not a full solution but that could allow to create different size list. That's better than nothing.